# I am using android studio and the mainactivity class is .kt type. I keep having this error: Expecting member declaration

Tags: kotlin

I am using android studio and I have some issues with this piece of code. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? 
The system keeps telling me "Expecting member declaration."

This is the code

```
class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

   class TextView totalTextView;    //This is where I am having the error 

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are trying to create a totalTextView variable. In kotlin you can declare a variable like this

```
lateinit var totalTextView : TotalTextView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is not right way to create or define object of TextView.

1 > var totalTextView : TextView ? = null
1 > lateint var totalTextView : TextView 


In kotlin, No need to define id of ViewGroup items , avoid to define the instance of view item  when you are using kotlin
```